# App not installed Release apk. Code -22 android Reason : Other

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-3.8.0

I’m building an release apk in ionic 3. Build goes successful but apk is not installed. Its gives me and error app not installed. Reason : other and code -22.

[image]